# Как преобразовать string в url ссылку

Tags: android, kotlin, url

Подскажите, пожалуйста как преобразовать   полученную из базы данных MSQL строку (string)  в url ссылку (андроид студио, язык Kotlin). То есть, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку происходила активация url ссылки, и пользователя перенаправляло на веб-ресурс.

Я использовал parse статический метод из Uri, но строка в url ссылку не активировалась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код

```
class Gubin : DialogFragment() {

    private var binding: GubinBinding? = null
    private val siteViewModel: SiteViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.gubin, container, false)
        binding?.idPharm?.text = arguments?.getString("id").toString()
        loadSite()

        return binding?.root
    }

    private fun loadSite() {

        siteViewModel.loadOneSit(binding?.idPharm?.text as String)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                binding?.urlSite?.text = it.last().url


              Uri.parse(Uri.decode(STRING.toString()))
                webView.loadUrl("")
               
            })
    }

}
```

`xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/idPharm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/urlSite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="lobster_regular"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/idPharm" />


            <WebView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/webView">

            </WebView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Url.parse( STRING )

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос, про какую кнопку идет речь? В разметке только две TextView и WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант — выставить у `TextView` атрибут [`autoLink`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:autoLink) в значение `web`. Тогда все ссылки в `TextView` станут кликабельными:

```xml
<TextView
    ...
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="Open https://google.com" />
```

Результат:

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо сделать из TextView ccылку, то можно воспользоваться такой функцией:

```
private fun setupHyperlink(linkTextView: TextView, url: Uri) {
    // формируем ссылку по ulr 
    // ссылка должна обязательно начинаться с протокола http либо https
    // иначе приложение будет вылетать с ошибкой 
    // android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
    var html = "<a href=\"$url\">$url</a>";
    // помещаем ссылку в тектовое поле
    linkTextView.text = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml(html)
    }
    // разрешеаем открыть ссылку по нажатию (без этого она будет не кликабельна)
    linkTextView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance();
}
```

Если нужно просто по нажатию кнопки открыть браузер с указанной ссылкой можно воспользоваться этой функцией:

```
private fun openWebPage(url: String) {
    var browserIntent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

**Дополнение:**

Применение второй функции может быть проблематично из-за адаптера, поэтому опишу как можно это решить, основная трудность связана не столько с открытием браузера сколько с указанием точного `url` и необходимостью `context` для запуска браузера.

- в `pharmacyModel` должен быть `url`
- в адаптер в методе `onBindViewHolder` добавляем следующий код, связывая `url` модели  c `tag` кнопки, чтобы иметь к нему доступ в обработчике

  ```
   holder.button.tag = pharmacyModel.url
   holder.button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
       openWebPage(view.tag.toString(), holder.button.context);
   })
  ```
- добавляем саму функцию `openWebPage` в адапер

Выглядеть она будет чуть иначе:

```
private fun openWebPage(url: String, context: Context) {
    var intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Таким образом, при клике на кнопку значение `url` считывается из нее самой и браузер открывается с указанным там адресом.

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Посмотреть" пользователя автоматически перенаправляло на конкретную web ссылку, то есть чтобы открывалась именно та Аптека, которая кратко прописана в определенном блоке (см. скрин).

Comment: @Андроидразработчик-Kotlin тогда используйте вторую функцию, навешиваете на клик, по id кнопки или как у Вас там уже организовано берете url и передаете в функцию откроется браузер (или будет выбор браузера если их несколько, первый раз)

Comment: @Андроидразработчик-Kotlin мне кажется Вы хотели это добавить в свой вопрос? заодно стоит указать как вы получаете url в классе карточки, разметка тут не сильно важна, главное что есть кнопка

Comment: @Андроидразработчик-Kotlin попробуйте внедрить в класс карточки метод `openWebPage` должно помочь, остальные детали в ответе мне кажутся лишними, первый вариант с `setupHyperlink` я оставляю для тех кто будет искать разные варианты на **stackowerflow**

Comment: с помощью android:autoLink="web" ссылка стала активной, но не знаю как реализовать, чтобы ссылка сразу срабатывала при нажатии на кнопку "Посмотреть", а не появлялась на экране и требовала повторного нажатия для ее активации.

Comment: Все данные в приложение поступают с двух таблиц базы данных MSQL (с сервера -Beget).

Comment: метод openWebPage  не сработал (

Comment: @Андроидразработчик-Kotlin вывалилась ошибка? я у себя на фрагменте проверял страница открывалась

Comment: Сделал одну базу данных MSQL, но все выше перечисленные методы не работают.

Comment: честно говоря не понимаю в чем может быть дело, должны быть как минимум какие-то ошибки, или это нужно видеть